# Extract JSTL value from a list in to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jstl

I have an issue where I am doing like this:

```
<Script>
var counts=1;
travelExpense.value='<c:out value="${customerPO.roleList["'+counts+'"].travelExpense}"/>';
</Script>
```

but I am unable to concatenate "counts" js variable with JSTLtag.It says  Unterminated`<c:out` 
I am unable to write the correct syntax for the same

Comment: You cannot do this; it makes no sense. Your JSP code is evaluated on the **server**, and the result sent to the client browser. The JavaScript code isn't evaluated until it's there, and at that point all traces of the JSP/JSTL code are gone.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the second concatenation character:

```
<Script>
var counts=1;
travelExpense.value='<c:out value="${customerPO.roleList["'+counts+'"].travelExpense}"/>';
//                                                            HERE^
</Script>
```

Update given the new information.  Try escaping the quotes that go around `count`:

```
<Script>
var counts=1;
travelExpense.value='<c:out value="${customerPO.roleList[\'' + counts + '\'].travelExpense}"/>';
</Script>
```

This yields the following string:

`<c:out value="${customerPO.roleList['1'].travelExpense}"/>`

As an aside, are you sure the `1` should be quoted?  If `roleList` is an array then this should work:

```
travelExpense.value='<c:out value="${customerPO.roleList[' + counts + '].travelExpense}"/>';
```

Giving:

`<c:out value="${customerPO.roleList[1].travelExpense}"/>`

Comment: sorryy for the typo..... i havve updated the same in the question.I was having the string as travelExpense.value='<c:out value="${customerPO.roleList["'+counts+'"].travelExpense}"/>'; but no luck

Comment: It is inherently nonsensical to attempt to combine the value of a JavaScript value with a (**server-side**) JSTL expression.

Comment: roleList is a list actually and when I am implementing the second way it gives me this errorjava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " + counts + "

Comment: Thanks a lot... your first solution did work after all.saved a lot of my effort.I do understand your point of mixing jstl and js, but it was a nessecary workaroundI had to do

Comment: I tried the first approach though there were no errors but it did not work out as expected ... your second approach was something which I need . but it is giving me number format exception